# How to increase pool size for tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, output, memory

I have a large document, and after compilation using tex4ht I observed that output html file did not contain all text. Some sections were missed.

It seems to me that memory pool is not enough.

How can I increase memory pool for tex4ht to have all text in output file?
Maybe there are some compilation arguments to configure this.

Or maybe anyone knows another decision.

Thank you in advance.

**EDITED:**

From log file:

--- file applicationmanualch44.html ---
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3176914].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the  pool size with `--pool-size=size` option for LaTeX. You can pass LaTeX options as 5th parameter to `htlatex` script:

```
htlatex filename xhtml "" "" " --pool-size=5000000"
```

note that space after `"` is important!

Comment: I don't know why, hovewer I got an error:
! I can't find file `--pool-size=5000000'.
<*>  --pool-size=5000000
                         \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def...